# Not able to insert data into Azure SQL Datawarehouse with Multiple lines in a column

Tags: azure-sql-database

I have source as a flat file having data in multiple lines in a string column, when I insert the same data into Azure SQL Datawarehouse database, its removing the new line characters and data is appearing in a single line.

I checked the data by copying into Notepad++ , its appearing in a single line.

Is there any option in Azure SQL Datawarehouse database to fix this issue.

Example:

```
 CREATE  TABLE test
     (
      ID VARCHAR(20) ,
      TASK NVARCHAR(100)
      ) 
      WITH ( CLUSTERED INDEX ( ID ) )
```

**Insert into table with multiple lines in TASK field**

```
insert into test values ('3','hello \n
world  \n
how \n
 are you')
```

**Output:**  3, hello world how are you

**Required output:**

> 3,    hello
>           world
>            how
>            are you

Appreciate for any inputs here.

Thank You!